# Push an object from an array into another array javascript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, push

I am having an issue with pushing an object into an array. I am fetching an array of objects from a local .json file. I am trying to create a function that pushes the given object into an array, so I can use it later on.

This is how I am receiving my object.

```
{id: 3176, name: "Matthias Ginter", position: "Defender", dateOfBirth: "1994-01-03T00:00:00Z", countryOfBirth: "Germany", …}
countryOfBirth: "Germany"
dateOfBirth: "1994-01-03T00:00:00Z"
id: 3176
name: "Matthias Ginter"
nationality: "Germany"
position: "Defender"
role: "PLAYER"
__proto__: Object
```

My code in React:

```
{data.map(
                        (player) => (
                            player.position == null ? (player.position = "Coach") : null,
                            (
                                <PlayerCard
                                    name={player.name}
                                    position={player.position}
                                    dateOfBirth={player.dateOfBirth}
                                    nationality={player.nationality}
                                    id={player.id}
                                    handleClick={() => selectedPlayers.push(player)}
                                />
                            )
                        )
                    )}
```

and the array I am trying to push into:

```
let selectedPlayers = [
        {
            id: 3176,
            name: "Matthias Ginter",
            position: "Defender",
            dateOfBirth: "1994-01-03T00:00:00Z",
            countryOfBirth: "Germany",
            nationality: "Germany",
            role: "PLAYER",
        },
        {
            id: 3176,
            name: "Mat Giensien",
            position: "Defender",
            dateOfBirth: "1994-01-03T00:00:00Z",
            countryOfBirth: "Germany",
            nationality: "Germany",
            role: "PLAYER",
        },
    ];
```

if I do `handleClick = {() => {console.log(player)}}` I get the object as shown above. What am I missing ?!

I read through all the topics here in SO but couldn't find a solution that would work for me. I have tried all the reccomended ways in the other topics and they still don't work for me.

**Please**, halp meeeeh :)

Comment: Hi, can you provide minimal working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello Rakesh. Basically I am trying to push the object(top section of code) into the array of objects (the bottom section of code) using the code in the middle or more specifically the  `handleClick={() => selectedPlayers.push(player)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{data.map(player => {
    return (
        <PlayerCard
            name={player.name}
            position={player.position ? "Coach" : null}
            dateOfBirth={player.dateOfBirth}
            nationality={player.nationality}
            id={player.id}
            handleClick={() => selectedPlayers.push(player)}
        />
    )
)}
```

Comment: that didn't help am afraid :/

Comment: @DenisDenchev too bad. I'm upvoting you for visibility. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let selectedPlayers = [
    {
        id: 3176,
        name: "Matthias Ginter",
        position: "Defender",
        dateOfBirth: "1994-01-03T00:00:00Z",
        countryOfBirth: "Germany",
        nationality: "Germany",
        role: "PLAYER"
    },
    {
        id: 3176,
        name: "Mat Giensien",
        position: "Defender",
        dateOfBirth: "1994-01-03T00:00:00Z",
        countryOfBirth: "Germany",
        nationality: "Germany",
        role: "PLAYER"
    }
];

let newData = {id: 9999, name: "bob jones", position: "goalkepper", dateOfBirth: "2020-01-03T00:00:00Z", nationality: "Spain", role: "MANAGER"}

 selectedPlayers.push(newData);


 console.log( selectedPlayers );
```

You might have to mess around with the formatting of the recevied object and the object you're pushing into to make iy work properly. But, if you're in control of the code and the JSON file then that shouldn't be an issue...